# ERROR TypeError: this.locations[0].getCoordinates is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

When I try to call the method of my `class (getCoordinates())` I get the following Error:

> ERROR TypeError: this.locations[0].getCoordinates is not a function

Where is my mistake?

My service method:

```
getLocations(){
    return this.http.get<Location[]>(this.locationUrl);
  }
```

My model:

```
export class Location {
    id: number;
    objectTypeId: number;
    type: string;
    fields: Fields;
    fav: boolean;
    typeless: boolean;
    pages: number;
    lastmodified: string;

    public getCoordinates(): number {
        return this.id;
    }
}

export class Fields {
    city: string;
    street: string;
    company: string;
    plz: string;
    info: string;
}
```

My component:

```
public locations: Array<Location> = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.getAddresses();
  }

getAddresses() {
    this.enaioService.getLocations()
      .subscribe(data => 
        this.locations = data,
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => this.errorMessage = error.message
      );
  }

onClick() {
    console.log(this.locations[0].getCoordinates()); // Here the error occurs
  }
```

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bjgtn4
```

My Project: https://bitbucket.org/sven_hagemann/myproject/src/master/

Clone: git clone https://sven_hagemann@bitbucket.org/sven_hagemann/myproject.git

Comment: Check what the value of `this.locations[0]` is

Comment: Wouldn't `this.http.get<Location[]>(this.locationUrl);` return some observable that will yield JSON data (which you typecast to `Location`). Or does some magic happen underneath it all? Can you send a dump of the contents of `this.locations`?

Comment: Please mentioned the data that you get in this.locations[0]. It will be helpful to solve your problem.

Comment: @Phillip: locations: Array<Location> = [];

Comment: @SunnyParekh -> this.locations[0]:
 {id: "47973", objectTypeId: "6", type: "FOLDER", fields: {…}, fav: false, …} fav: false fields: {city: "Henstedt-Ulzburg", street: "Hamburger Straße 55", company: "# 300 339 #", plz: "24558", info: ""} id: "47973" lastmodified: "1538143201000" objectTypeId: "6" pages: 0 type: "FOLDER" typeless: false proto: Object

Comment: @David: The value of this.locations[0] see message before.

Comment: @SNMP ok. In this object you are trying to call the getCoordinates method. And I am not seeing that in the object anywhere. So can you explain what do you want by calling that method? Is it some property that you are trying to access? Please clarify.

Comment: Here is a link to stackbiz: stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bjgtn4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because, the list of `Location` objects retrieved from your `getLocations` method are not instances of the `Location` class. What you have now is just typescript syntaxic sugar, saying that what is returned by `getLocations` *should* have the properties of the `Location` class, but it does not have to.

You need to modify your code as follows to return real instances of the `Location` class

```
import {map} from "rxjs/operators";

getLocations(): Observable<Location[]>
{
    return this.http.get(this.locationUrl).pipe
    (map( (items: any[]) => items.map(i => Object.assign(new Location(), i));
    ));
 }
```

Comment: why i need to iterate over all items. There should be some simpler way of doing it.

Comment: @Sameer I don't think there is any other way. You've got a list of objects from which you wang to create instances of  `Location` class, so you need to do that for each item

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
getLocations(): Observable<Location[]>{
    return this.http.get<Location[]>(this.locationUrl)
  .pipe(map( (items: any[]) => 
   items.map(i => Object.assign(new Location(), i)); ));

}
```

Comment: Thanks Sameer, but that does not solve my problem yet.

Comment: what is value of this.locations[0] object ?

Comment: Hi Sameer, here's the value:

{id: "47973", objectTypeId: "6", type: "FOLDER", fields: {…}, fav: false, …}
fav: false
fields: {city: "Henstedt-Ulzburg", street: "Hamburger Straße 55", company: "# 300 339 #", plz: "24558", info: ""}
id: "47973"
lastmodified: "1538143201000"
objectTypeId: "6"
pages: 0
type: "FOLDER"
typeless: false
__proto__: Object

Comment: try to remove public access modifier. I not sure about that what problem you are facing

Comment: I did it, but unfortunately the result is the same.

Comment: Then you need to create stackbiz link. if want more help